# Javascript code produces errors when moved from inline to external file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a copy script built in to the page I am working on, and when the copy JS is inline, it works great, but as soon as I moved it external, it produces the following error:
`copy.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

I am unsure why because when inline there is no issues. Copy of the section code is:

```
    <?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "brandina_templat", "REMOVED", "brandina_templates");  
$catresult = "SELECT * FROM categories";
$catquery = mysqli_query($connect,$catresult);
$catquery2 = mysqli_query($connect,$catresult);
?>
<html>  
      <head>  
           <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
           <title>Templates Sheet | Brandin Arsenault's</title>    
           <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
           <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>  
           <script src="js/tabcontent.js"></script> 
           <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
      </head>   
      <body>  
       <div class="container">  
                <br />  
                <h1 align="center">Templates Sheet</h1>
                    <center><ul class="tabs">
<?php
    if(!$catquery)
    {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($catquery))
        {
            $number=$row['number'];
            $tabname=$row['tabname'];
            $catname=$row['catname'];
            echo "<li class='tab-link' data-tab='$tabname'>$catname</li>";
        }
?>
        </ul>
<?php
    if(!$catquery2)
    {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($catquery2))
        {
            $number=$row['number'];
            $tabname=$row['tabname'];
            $catname=$row['catname'];
            $result = "SELECT * FROM templates WHERE category=$number";
            $query = mysqli_query($connect,$result);
            echo "<div id='$tabname' class='tab-content'>
                                        <table><center>";
                    $c = 0;
                    $n = 3;
                if(!$query)
                    {
                        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
                    }
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                            {
                                $id=$row['id'];
                                $longname=$row['longname'];
                                $shortname=$row['shortname'];
                                $text=$row['text'];
                                    if($c % $n == 0 && $c != 0)
                                        {
                                            echo '</tr><tr>';
                                        }
                                    $c++;
                                    echo "
                                        <td>
                        <center><b>$longname</b></center><textarea id='$id' cols='25' rows='3'>$text</textarea><br /><button id='$shortname'>Copy</button>
                                        </td>
                                        <script>
                                            var shortname = '$shortname';
                                        </script>";
                            }
            echo "</center></table></div>";
        }
?>
<script src='js/copy.js'></script>
</center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

copy.js is:

```
    document.getElementById(shortname).addEventListener('click', function() {
    copyToClipboardMsg(document.getElementById('$id'), 'msg');
});
function copyToClipboardMsg(elem, msgElem) {
      var succeed = copyToClipboard(elem);
    var msg;
    if (!succeed) {
        msg = 'Copy not supported or blocked.  Press Ctrl+c to copy.'
    } else {
        msg = 'Text copied to the clipboard.'
    }
    if (typeof msgElem === 'string') {
        msgElem = document.getElementById(msgElem);
    }
    msgElem.innerHTML = msg;
    setTimeout(function() {
        msgElem.innerHTML = '';
    }, 2000);
}

function copyToClipboard(elem) {
      // create hidden text element, if it doesn't already exist
    var targetId = '_hiddenCopyText_';
    var isInput = elem.tagName === 'INPUT' || elem.tagName === 'TEXTAREA';
    var origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd;
    if (isInput) {
        // can just use the original source element for the selection and copy
        target = elem;
        origSelectionStart = elem.selectionStart;
        origSelectionEnd = elem.selectionEnd;
    } else {
        // must use a temporary form element for the selection and copy
        target = document.getElementById(targetId);
        if (!target) {
            var target = document.createElement('textarea');
            target.style.position = 'absolute';
            target.style.left = '-9999px';
            target.style.top = '0';
            target.id = targetId;
            document.body.appendChild(target);
        }
        target.textContent = elem.textContent;
    }
    // select the content
    var currentFocus = document.activeElement;
    target.focus();
    target.setSelectionRange(0, target.value.length);

    // copy the selection
    var succeed;
    try {
          succeed = document.execCommand('copy');
    } catch(e) {
        succeed = false;
    }
    // restore original focus
    if (currentFocus && typeof currentFocus.focus === 'function') {
        currentFocus.focus();
    }

    if (isInput) {
        // restore prior selection
        elem.setSelectionRange(origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd);
    } else {
        // clear temporary content
        target.textContent = '';
    }
    return succeed;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your PHP interpreter running on all files locally?

Comment: Maybe remove the dollar signs for the ID `$shortname`?

Comment: @BrandinArsenault, Updated my answer, you can check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `$shortname` exists when you use the inline code, but when you move your code to external it doesn't exists anymore.

You can use:

```
<script>
    var shortname = '$shortname';
</script>
<script src='js/copy.js'></script>
```

And in your copy.js file you should use:

```
document.getElementById(shortname).addEventListener('click', function() {
```

Otherwise - the javascript code is looking for element that it's id is `$shortname`, and you don't really have one with the value.

Comment: thank you for replying. JS continues to produce the error as in my original post. I am unsure why. I used your steps, and totally understand what you're saying, but it sadly is not fixing the issue.

Comment: 1. How do you print the variables? 2. What you html looks like?

Comment: 1. You don't really want to set the `<script src="js/copy.js">` inside the loop. 2. the `shortname` inside `getElementById` should be without the quotes (it's the name of the variable, not the string)

Comment: I appreciate you helping me with this. I have moved the script defining the `var` in in and outside of the loop. Inside the loop, no errors are produced, but no function happens when using the Copy button. Outside of the loop, it produces the original error. I have made the suggested changes to the `getElementById` function and this is occuring. I appreciate you helping me with this.

Comment: Without looking at your complete code, after the changes, it's hard to help. Note that instead of using `id` you might want to use some other selector (like class, which is not unique).

Comment: I have posted the updated version. Could you provide an example of the class selector you are referencing. I think I understand, but not 100 on that.

Comment: It looks like you have the some problem with the `$id` variable. check your code... `document.getElementById('$id'),`

Comment: I had removed this and changed it to `id`, by itself, as recommended with the `shortname`, and change it to `shortname`, this made no difference sadly.

Comment: I'm really scratching my head on this one, because all of your suggestions make sense and have enlightened my understanding of this specific situation, but I cannot figure it out. It seems as if all we need to do is get the variable to post to the JS function, but I cannot for the life of me make it work.

Comment: I had edited it out instead of leaving three different types of code in there. They all produce no error, `id` `$id` `shortname` `$shortname` when in the second line of `copyToClipboardMsg`. However, the function is still broken.